# Throughput and speed of data transmission cables

Tags: cables, data, bandwidth, speed

What are throughput and speed limiting factors in an ethernet or any other type of cable which is used for data transmission?

Comment: This question is rather broad and the answer depends on how much theory you already know; but the short answer is "Shannon-Harley theorem" also known as the "Shannon limit".

Comment: @pjc50 - I assume you mean [Shannon–Har**T**ley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem). Maybe upgrade that, with an explanation, to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/antennas/coax/coax_loss.php) and note that it doesn't just apply to coaxial cable - skin effect and dielectric losses are a real problem for all cables wishing to relay signals at high frequencies.